# Password reset bug? - "Sorry, that key does not appear to be valid"

Tags: password

Recently my WordPress website's reset password function has started to not work.

When a user clicks the link that the 'forgot your password?' link sends out, it displays the error "Sorry, that key does not appear to be valid.".

I searched through some internet forums and this seems like a well-known issue, yet there is no consensus on a solution.

I tried disabling most of the plugins that I installed recently and custom functions I put in, but the problem just persists. Does anyone know what could be the problem? I hope it is not a wordpress bug that came with an automatic update.

Thank you

Comment: Please try it again with all plugins disabled and with default theme? Is problem still there?

Comment: I would like to try that but my website consistently has at least 70 users using it at any given moment. It is very difficult for me to disable the plugins because it will affect the website's functionality. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: You can clone your whole site to another staging environment and perform required testing there.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it took me all week to figure it out. I know OP has probably solved it by now, but for the others like me who surfed here looking for answers:

Open the wp-config.php file and use this website ( https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ ) to replace the lines of code that start with:  "define ('AUTH_KEY',  'blablabla');"

Please backup the file and/or comment out the old lines, just in case!  Hope it works for you also!

Comment: Replacing salt key doesn't solve it.